# Count the number of keys in a postgres json field using a django query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is a stripped down definition of the table:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields as pg_fields
class MyTable(models.Model):
    data = pg_fields.JSONField()
```

I would like to write the below as a pure Django query instead of writing the raw sql:

```
MyTable.objects.raw("""
    SELECT 
        id,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jsonb_object_keys(data)) AS val
    FROM myapp_mytable
    ORDER BY val
""")
```

(use of `from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL` is acceptable within an annotation if required)